# Video and Screen sharing with agora not working when VR headset connected in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, agora.io

It is the same code as the code you get following the video sdk docs when implementing broadcast streaming for unity. Both video and screen sharing is working when using 2 computers. However as soon as i connect a vr headset to one of the computers, the video and screen sharing stops working for that computer.

Does anyone know why?
Using video sdk 4.2.6 and unity 2021.3.16f1
This was a htc vive wireless headset. Havent tried on the varjo xr-3 yet, but it needs to work for different types of headsets so.

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Agora.Rtc;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

#if (UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID)
using UnityEngine.Android;
#endif

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
#if (UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID)
private ArrayList permissionList = new ArrayList() { Permission.Camera, Permission.Microphone };
#endif

private string _appID = "";
private string appCertificate = "";
private string _channelName = "";
private string uid = "";
private string userAccount = "";
private int expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600;
private string _token = "";

// A variable to hold the user role.
private string clientRole = "";
// A variable to save the remote user uid.
private uint remoteUid;
private Toggle toggle1;
private Toggle toggle2;
internal VideoSurface LocalView;
internal VideoSurface RemoteView;
internal IRtcEngine RtcEngine;
// Volume Control
private Slider volumeSlider;
// Screen sharing
private bool sharingScreen = false;
private TMP_Text shareScreenBtnText;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    SetupVideoSDKEngine();
    InitEventHandler();
    SetupUI();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    CheckPermissions();
}

private void CheckPermissions()
{
    #if (UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID)
    foreach (string permission in permissionList)
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(permission))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(permission);
        }
    }
    #endif
}

private string GenerateToken()
{
    return _token;
}

private void SetupUI()
{
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find("LocalView");
    LocalView = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
    go.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 180.0f);
    go = GameObject.Find("RemoteView");
    RemoteView = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
    go.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 180.0f);
    go = GameObject.Find("Leave");
    go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Leave);
    go = GameObject.Find("Join");
    go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Join);
    GameObject Obj1 = GameObject.Find("Broadcaster");
    toggle1 = Obj1.GetComponent<Toggle>();
    toggle1.isOn = false;
    toggle1.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
    {
        Func1(value);
    });
    GameObject Obj2 = GameObject.Find("Audience");
    toggle2 = Obj2.GetComponent<Toggle>();
    toggle2.isOn = false;
    toggle2.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
    {
        Func2(value);
    });
    // Access the button from the UI.
    go = GameObject.Find("shareScreen");
    // Add a listener to the button and invokes shareScreen when the button is pressed.
    go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(ShareScreen);
    // Access the text sub-item of the screen sharing button to change the button text.
    shareScreenBtnText = go.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>(true);
    shareScreenBtnText.text = "Share Screen";
    shareScreenBtnText.fontSize = 14;
    // Access the slider from the UI
    go = GameObject.Find("mediaProgressBar");
    volumeSlider = go.GetComponent<Slider>();
    // Specify a maximum value for the slider.
    go.GetComponent<Slider>().maxValue = 100;
    // Add a listener to the slider and invokes changeVolume when the value changes.
    go.GetComponent<Slider>().onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ChangeVolume((int)volumeSlider.value); });
    // Access the Mute toggle from the UI.
    go = GameObject.Find("Mute");
    Toggle muteToggle = go.GetComponent<Toggle>();
    muteToggle.isOn = false;
    // Invoke muteRemoteAudio when the user taps the toggle button.
    muteToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
    {
        MuteRemoteAudio(value);
    });
}

private void ChangeVolume(int volume)
{
    // Adjust the recorded signal volume.
    RtcEngine.AdjustRecordingSignalVolume(volume);
}

private void MuteRemoteAudio(bool value)
{
    // Pass the uid of the remote user you want to mute.
    RtcEngine.MuteRemoteAudioStream(System.Convert.ToUInt32(remoteUid), value);
}

private void UpdateChannelPublishOptions(bool publishMediaPlayer)
{
    ChannelMediaOptions channelOptions = new ChannelMediaOptions();
    channelOptions.publishScreenTrack.SetValue(publishMediaPlayer);
    channelOptions.publishMicrophoneTrack.SetValue(true);
    channelOptions.publishSecondaryScreenTrack.SetValue(publishMediaPlayer);
    channelOptions.publishCameraTrack.SetValue(!publishMediaPlayer);
    RtcEngine.UpdateChannelMediaOptions(channelOptions);
}

private void SetupLocalVideo(bool isScreenSharing)
{
    if (isScreenSharing)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("LocalView");
        go.transform.Rotate(-180.0f, 0.0f, 180.0f);
        // Update the VideoSurface component of the local view.
        LocalView = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        // Render the screen sharing track on the local view.
        LocalView.SetForUser(0, "", VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE.VIDEO_SOURCE_SCREEN_PRIMARY);

    }
    else
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("LocalView");
        go.transform.Rotate(180.0f, 0.0f, 180.0f);
        // Update the VideoSurface component of the local view.
        LocalView = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        // Render the local video track on the local view.
        LocalView.SetForUser(0, "", VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE.VIDEO_SOURCE_CAMERA_PRIMARY);
    }
}

public void ShareScreen()
{
    if (!sharingScreen)
    {
        // The target size of the screen or window thumbnail (the width and height are in pixels).
        SIZE t = new SIZE(360, 240);
        // The target size of the icon corresponding to the application program (the width and height are in pixels)
        SIZE s = new SIZE(360, 240);
        // Get a list of shareable screens and windows
        var info = RtcEngine.GetScreenCaptureSources(t, s, true);
        Debug.LogError("info: " + info.Length);
        // Get the first source id to share the whole screen.
        ulong dispId = (ulong)info[4].sourceId;
        ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < info.Length; i++)
        {
            names.Add(info[i].sourceName);
        }

        string result = string.Join("", names.ToArray());
        Debug.LogError("result: " + result);
        Debug.LogError("dispId: " + dispId);
        // To share a part of the screen, specify the screen width and size using the Rectangle class.
        RtcEngine.StartScreenCaptureByWindowId(System.Convert.ToUInt32(dispId), new Rectangle(),
            default(ScreenCaptureParameters));
        // Publish the screen track and unpublish the local video track.
        UpdateChannelPublishOptions(true);
        // Display the screen track in the local view.
        SetupLocalVideo(true);
        // Change the screen sharing button text.
        shareScreenBtnText.text = "Stop Sharing";
        // Update the screen sharing state.
        sharingScreen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Stop sharing.
        RtcEngine.StopScreenCapture();
        // Publish the local video track when you stop sharing your screen.
        UpdateChannelPublishOptions(false);
        // Display the local video in the local view.
        SetupLocalVideo(false);
        // Update the screen sharing state.
        sharingScreen = false;
        // Change to the default text of the button when you stop sharing your screen.
        shareScreenBtnText.text = "Share Screen";
    }
}

private void SetupVideoSDKEngine()
{
    // Create an instance of the video SDK.
    RtcEngine = Agora.Rtc.RtcEngine.CreateAgoraRtcEngine();
    // Specify the context configuration to initialize the created instance.
    RtcEngineContext context = new RtcEngineContext(_appID, 0,
        CHANNEL_PROFILE_TYPE.CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING,
        AUDIO_SCENARIO_TYPE.AUDIO_SCENARIO_DEFAULT, AREA_CODE.AREA_CODE_GLOB, null);
    // Initialize the created instance.
    RtcEngine.Initialize(context);
}

private void InitEventHandler()
{
    // Creates a UserEventHandler instance.
    UserEventHandler handler = new UserEventHandler(this);
    RtcEngine.InitEventHandler(handler);
}

public void Join()
{
    //_token = GenerateToken();
    if (toggle1.isOn == false && toggle2.isOn == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("Select a role first");
    }
    else
    {
        // Enable the video module.
        RtcEngine.EnableVideo();
        // Set the local video view.
        LocalView.SetForUser(0, "", VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE.VIDEO_SOURCE_CAMERA);
        // Join a channel.
        RtcEngine.JoinChannel(_token, _channelName);
    }
}

internal class UserEventHandler : IRtcEngineEventHandler
{
    private readonly NewBehaviourScript _videoSample;

    internal UserEventHandler(NewBehaviourScript videoSample)
    {
        _videoSample = videoSample;
    }
    // This callback is triggered when the local user joins the channel.
    public override void OnJoinChannelSuccess(RtcConnection connection, int elapsed)
    {
        Debug.Log("You joined channel: " + connection.channelId);
    }
    public override void OnUserJoined(RtcConnection connection, uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        // Setup remote view.
        _videoSample.RemoteView.SetForUser(uid, connection.channelId, VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE.VIDEO_SOURCE_REMOTE);
        if (_videoSample.clientRole == "Audience")
        {
            // Start rendering remote video.
            _videoSample.RemoteView.SetEnable(true);
        }
        _videoSample.remoteUid = uid;
    }

    public override void OnClientRoleChanged(RtcConnection connection, CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE oldRole, CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE newRole, ClientRoleOptions newRoleOptions)
    {
        if (newRole == CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER)
        {
            _videoSample.LocalView.SetEnable(true);
            _videoSample.RemoteView.SetEnable(false);
            Debug.Log("Role changed to Broadcaster");
        }
        else
        {
            _videoSample.LocalView.SetEnable(false);
            _videoSample.RemoteView.SetEnable(true);
            Debug.Log("Role changed to Audience");
        }
    }

    // This callback is triggered when a remote user leaves the channel or drops offline.
    public override void OnUserOffline(RtcConnection connection, uint uid, USER_OFFLINE_REASON_TYPE reason)
    {
        _videoSample.RemoteView.SetEnable(false);
    }
}

public void Leave()
{
    // Leaves the channel.
    RtcEngine.LeaveChannel();
    // Disable the video modules.
    RtcEngine.DisableVideo();
    // Stops rendering the remote video.
    RemoteView.SetEnable(false);
    // Stops rendering the local video.
    LocalView.SetEnable(false);
}

void Func1(bool value)
{
    if (value == true)
    {
        toggle2.isOn = false;
        RtcEngine.SetClientRole(CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER);
        clientRole = "Host";
    }
}
void Func2(bool value)
{
    if (value == true)
    {
        toggle1.isOn = false;
        RtcEngine.SetClientRole(CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE.CLIENT_ROLE_AUDIENCE);
        clientRole = "Audience";
    }
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    if (RtcEngine != null)
    {
        Leave();
        RtcEngine.Dispose();
        RtcEngine = null;
    }
}
}
```